# how to select col1 value x and copy to new row with col1 value y,if run query again,should not copy again

Tags: sql, db2

how to copy rows to same table where select column1 value = 55 and to new row with column 1 value = 56, **if we run query second time, it should not copy the old lines again**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `where` clause to prevent a duplicate insert using `not exists`:

```
insert  YourTable
        (col1, col2, col3, ...)
select  56 -- New value
,       col2
,       col3
,       ...
from    YourTable
where   col1 = 55 -- Old value
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   col1 = 56 -- New value
        )
```

Comment: Sir Andomar 
we have to select existing one 55 (old value) and add that row value with new value 56

As you have written insert  YourTable
        (col1, col2, col3, ...)
select  56 -- New value  .. will not that search for 56 value to copy instead of copying 55 ?

Comment: Please don't Sir me.   This answer will search for the row with value 55 and create a copy, replacing 55 with 56 in col1.

Comment: okay Andomar i wont Sir you .. :)
 .. its not working ..
actually i have to select 2 column values in where clause and have to check for just 56 in do not exist which is okay ..

error is just before not exists
"where col1 = 55                  
and col2 = x                         
and not exists (.....)

Comment: What error?  Perhaps you can create an example on sqlfiddle.com or data.stackexchange.com

Comment: i have done this ..
INSERT INTO DB2.table (a,b,c,d,e)           

SELECT 56,b,c,d,e from table
 WHERE a=55 
and b=x
and not exists                                                        
 (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   col1 = 56 -- New value
        )

Comment: Hi Andomar ... i got a problem with this above solution ...
i copies all the data of 55 to 56 well..
but if there exists a record in the table already with 56 which we have denied by not exists .. it do not allow a single row to be copied for any of the 55 record ..
just becoz we have 1 row with value 56 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  :(

Comment: Well, that's what your question asks for?  You can further restrict the "do not copy" conditions by adding other columns to the `where` clause in the `not exists` subquery.